# Integral of function having modulus

Tags: integration

> Evaluate
>
> $$ \int c e^{-|x-U|} dx$$ Assume $c$ and $U$ to be constant.

I am not used to do integrals since long time. I suddenly have to use this in a computer program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be a primitive such that $F(0)=0$. Then
$$
F(X)=\int_{U}^X c \, e^{-|x-U|}dx=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\int_{U}^X c \, e^{-x+U}dx &X>U \\ &\\ \int_{U}^X c \, e^{x-U}dx & X\le U\end{array}\right.=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}c \,(1-e^{U-X})& X>U \\ &\\ c\, (e^{X-U}-1)&X\le U\end{array}\right. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int{\rm e}^{-\left\vert x - U\right\vert}\,{\rm d}x
&=
-\int{\rm sgn}\left(x - U\right)
{{\rm d}{\rm e}^{-\left\vert x - U\right\vert} \over {\rm d}x}\,{\rm d}x
+
\mbox{constant}
\\[3mm]&=
-{\rm sgn}\left(x - U\right){\rm e}^{-\left\vert x - U\right\vert}
+
\int2\delta\left(x - U\right)
{\rm e}^{-\left\vert x - U\right\vert}\,{\rm d}x
+
\mbox{constant}
\\[3mm]&=
-{\rm sgn}\left(x - U\right){\rm e}^{-\left\vert x - U\right\vert}
+
\mbox{constant}
\end{align}